# inApp purchase... different products in 3 separate spots

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, uipopovercontroller, storekit

I have an in app purchase issue... I have an iPad app I'm upgrading. Previously used MKStoreKit. Started to upgrade to the latest version, but it turned out to be too complicated and too different to just "plug-in". Created a new "store kit" from scratch, which is much simpler and is built for iOS5+ and is ARC compliant.

Scenario: I have 3 spots to purchase. 1) is a full upgrade from a popover; 2) is an "icons" popover, which allows the user to purchase sets of icons for use in the app; 3) is a "backgrounds" popover, which allows the user to purchase sets of backgrounds for use in the app. All are in different views within the app.

Obviously, the available items all have to be available, but they also need to be segregated into the different popovers.

I have a "store manager" and a helper for the manager. The manager has a class method which includes all of the products listed in a set, and are accessed via a single "productIdentifier" variable in the manager. The actual items (images) are included in the app and are connected to an SQL database. I have played with additional sets, and have used subarrayWithRange. I have the correct number of sets showing in the popovers, although they are not showing the correct count, nor the correct images in each set.

I am looking for suggestions on how to separate these products into their unique "categories", while retaining the product identifier class of the manager, so that they feed back to the manager. I'm not looking for someone to solve it "for me"... I fully believe in solving one's own issues. I'm merely looking for a few suggestions in steering me in the correct path.

Should I create separate class methods for each type of purchase? Subsets within the main set?

Have any suggestions on how I could solve this issue? Any and all are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using a refresh table method. I simply use different ranges for the 3 different spots.

```
-(void)reloadData
{
    _products = nil;
    [TJ_IAPHelper.sharedInstance requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products)
     {
         // by using subarrayWithRange, we limit what is displayed in the table
         // those items that actually correspond to the background sets
         // from the Apple store
         _purchaseableBackgrounds = [products subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 6)];
         if (success)
         {
             _products = _purchaseableBackgrounds;
             [self.tableView reloadData];
         }
         [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
     }];
}
```